# What's the best way to write JavaScript/Ruby applications on Windows Mobile device?

Tags: javascript, ruby, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I recently bought a Windows Mobile device and since I'm a developer I want to use it as a development platform. Yes, it's not supposed to be used like that but it's always with me and my laptop isn't. I know [cke](http://www.animaniak.com/cke/cke_main.asp) is a good editor for code but how can I run JavaScript/Ruby code without too much of a headache?

I probably could write a web application, send code to it and get the results back but maybe there's better solutions?

Answer (score 4):

There is a possibility to run [**Ruby on Windows Mobile**](http://uema2.s8.xrea.com/ruby-mswince/)

Check this article for steps: [**Human vs Machine**](http://andryshuzain.com/journal/ruby-on-windows-mobile-5)

Javascript is bit crippled on Windows Mobile.
Follow up the discussions here: [**Windows Mobile IE Team Blog**](http://blogs.msdn.com/iemobile/archive/2006/04/06/570375.aspx)
Hopefully the next version if Pocket Internet Explorer supports better!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're interested, but there's only a port of Python for CE.

http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use etcl from Evolane (http://www.evolane.com/software/etcl).

It comes with console.

Answer (score 0):

This is n old port of Ruby to WinCE, but from what I've read it doesn't work all that well - who knows, give it a try, YMMV

http://uema2.s8.xrea.com/ruby-mswince/

As for Javascript, WinMo devices have Pocket Internet Explorer - it isn't very good, but runs some Javascript. If you want something that is a bit closer to a desktop you could install Opera.

Comment: Ruby "kind of" works but it's really slow and wants console, so it is just unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a Windows Mobile phone for just over a month and would also like to run code on it. Unfortunately it's such a limited platform with hardly any community support. It seems to me that the only decent choices are [Python](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/), [NSBASIC](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/) and [PPL](http://www.arianesoft.ca/page.php?1)

For Javascript, you'll be better off using Opera, opposed to Pocket Internet Explorer.

As for cke, I found [CEdit](http://www.logicalsky.com/Product_CEdit.htm) a more stable editor but you do have to pay for it. Though I don't think there is any editor that does syntax highlighting for Ruby on Window Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Rhomobile's open source framework Rhodes (www.rhomobile.com) works great on Windows Mobile.